# Why does this program print some kind of AST in the REPL?

Tags: idris

```
import Data.Nat.Views

total toBinary : Nat -> String
toBinary k with (halfRec k)
  toBinary Z | HalfRecZ = ""
  toBinary (n + n) | (HalfRecEven rec) = (toBinary n | rec) ++ "0"
  toBinary (S (n + n)) | (HalfRecOdd rec) = (toBinary n | rec) ++ "1"
```

When testing the above function in the REPL with the expression `toBinary 2`, the following gets printed out.

```
prim__concat (with block in Exercises.toBinary 1
                                           (with block in with block in Data.Nat.Views.halfRec 0
                                                                                               (half 0)
                                                                                               (Access (\z, zLTy =>
                                                                                                          Prelude.WellFounded.sizeAccessible, acc Nat
                                                                                                                                                  2
                                                                                                                                                  (constructor of Prelude.WellFounded.Sized (\meth =>
                                                                                                                                                                                               meth))
                                                                                                                                                  1
                                                                                                                                                  z
                                                                                                                                                  (lteTransitive zLTy
                                                                                                                                                                 (LTESucc LTEZero))))))
         "0" : String
```

When I run `:exec toBinary 2`, the expected result of `"10"` gets printed out.

Could anyone please explain what's happening?

Comment: [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Idris/comments/8teppj/weird_error_in_using_views/) may answer your qu